# Java trouble serializing a field of an object

Tags: java, serialization

I'm trying to learn about serialization and encountered the following problem:

I have an implementation of a customer that looks somewhat like this.

```
private static customerCount = 0;
private String customerID;
private String name;
private String street;
private String city;
private String postcode;
private String type;
```

I'm trying to serialize / deserialize an Arraylist

In the constructor, the ID will be created like this:

```
private Customer(...){
this.customerID = "ID" + customerCount;
customerCount++;
}
```

The serialization process works, however, all the IDs are set to `ID0` when I deserialize.
Can anyone help resolve this problem?

Update: Alright, I just found out that static fields wont be serialized. How can I "model" the ID of a customer so I can serialize it? I need to have a unique value to create IDs for customers.

Comment: static fields will not get serialized..

Comment: Thank you, I just read it up again and feel like an idiot. How would I go about modeling a unique ID for customers?

Comment: if you store customers in database, you can use auto increment id's

Comment: You could look at the last ID in the `ArrayList` and add 1 instead of having a static counter...

Comment: Or use a factory that keeps track of the customer count for you.

Comment: Thanks!! I have a factory, totally didnt think about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that combines the factory with the list that keeps track of customer count.

The customer class has a protected constructor, forcing you to build them through another means within the same package.

```
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    private String customerID;
    private String name;
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private String postcode;
    private String type;

    protected Customer(String customerID,
                    String name,
                    String street,
                    String city,
                    String postcode,
                    String type) {
        this.customerID = customerID;
        this.name = name;
        this.street = street;
        this.city = city;
        this.postcode = postcode;
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

Now within the package, create a list wrapper like this:

```
public class CustomerList {
    private int customerCount = 0;
    private List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();

    public boolean addCustomer(String name,
            String street,
            String city,
            String postcode,
            String type) {

        Customer customer = new Customer("ID" + customerCount++,
                name,
                street,
                city,
                postcode,
                type);

        return customers.add(customer);
    }
}
```

This class then takes care of constructing the new customer, and provides a unique ID.

Edit: Just noticed that you now also have the upside of making the CustomerList class serializable as well.  Then you can load it and still have an accurate customer count for adding additional uniquely ID-ed customers.

Comment: Thanks, the private constructor was a typing mistake, not in the actual code. This works just as I need it for that specific task!

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you would like to serialize only attributes and their values, not the logic from the class. Logic should happen before serialization or after deserialization.